# CentOS Apache/PHP exec function does not finish executing external program

Tags: php, apache, apache2, centos, exec

I have tried and failed to understand why my command line program does not work in Apache environment using a PHP exec() function call.  Here is the scenario:

1. Installed Apache 2.x and PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS 32-bit
2. Hard-coded a php file called myScript.php that contains a simple call to exec() such as: 
   exec("./imageManipuator testImage.jpg 512 512 >& output.log &");

The exec() function should call my program with the given parameters to process the request, redirect output to a file "output.log" all in a background process defined by '&'.

I check the log and the program executes 1/4 way through the program and terminates without a clue why.

I tried executing the PHP file via PHP Interactive shell call via:

$ php myScript.php

The execution of the program completely finishes!!!  That brings me to feel:

1. What is wrong with my Apache/PHP configuration to disallow my program to execute all the way.
2. Perhaps a permission issue?  I tried changing the logged user as the Administrator user but it did not change anything.
3. Perhaps a memory issue?  Shouldn't there be a warning or notification if a memory limit has been reached?  I have not verified this is the issue?

That is my issue.  I know I am using the function exec() correctly to execute the program in the background because the same script works when calling the same file via PHP Interactive shell.  What could be wrong in the Apache/PHP configuration that disallows my program to fully execute?

Any suggestions is a bonus as I have exhausted my ideas.

Comment: Don't run the process in the background. See what its return value is.

Comment: Let me guess, the `exec` call takes a bit of time. On the CLI, PHP's max_execution time is no-limit (0). Though system-calls aren't counted as exec-time, Apache does have a timeout limit. Check if the script hits the Apache limit, and raise it if needs must, or, better still, think about a way of _not_ calling the system when PHP is running in Apache

Comment: I like the quick replies, but:

Comment: I like the quick replies, but: <br/>  I tried not running the process in the background and the output is still the same (Sorry @MarcB), <br/> Also, the total execution time of the program is around 16-18 seconds which is well below the max limits.  To be safe I increased Apache Timeout and php.ini timeouts.  Also, to be safe, I increased php.ini max memory used to 1024MB instead of 128 and restarted the service.  Still, the program executed to the same spot.  I am still looking to see what else to do.  Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: time spent in external shells isn't counted against the php runtime. only actual time spent executing PHP code counts.

Comment: @MarcB: _"though system-calls aren't counted as exec-time, Apache does have a timeout limit"_ ==> it's not PHP timing out, it could be apache, getting tired of waiting for a reply